# Path/URI from sqlite load into Listview

Tags: android, listview, imageview, uri

I have a listview that loads information from sqlite database. The information should load image this way:

[image]

This is the code for the listview activity:

```
private void populateListViewFromDB() {
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

    // Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
    // DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] 
            {DBAdapter.KEY_DATE, DBAdapter.KEY_IMG, DBAdapter.KEY_FAVCOLOUR};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
            {R.id.item_date,     R.id.item_icon,           R.id.item_kcal};

    // Create adapter to may columns of the DB onto elemesnt in the UI.
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,       // Context
                    R.layout.item_layout,   // Row layout template
                    cursor,                 // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                    fromFieldNames,         // DB Column names
                    toViewIDs               // View IDs to put information in
                    );

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFromDB);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
```

Theoretically, I'm trying to save the string "snapPath" to the field "KEY_IMG" and load the image into imageview "item_icon". If the user does not snap a photo, by default, the imageview will load a drawable instead.

At the Add activity page, I added a string and save that string to the database:

```
String snapPath = "res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png"; //by default it will load a drawable
myDb.insertRow(date, snapPath, kcal+" kcal"); //saves into database
```

Also in Add activity page, the code for capturing and saving the image into my phone:

```
private void doTakePicture() {
    // create a File object for the parent directory
    File newDir = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/myFoodDiary/snaps");
    newDir.mkdirs();

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    //for file name
    Date cDate = new Date();
    final String fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMMd").format(cDate);
    final String fTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss").format(cDate);

    String snapName = "mFD-" + fDate + fTime + ".jpg";
    fileJpeg = new File(newDir, snapName);

    snapPath = "/myFoodDiary/snaps/"+String.valueOf(snapName);


    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(fileJpeg));
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PIC_REQ);

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To customize whether to draw a bitmap from storage or a drawable from your resources, you can't use `SimpleCursorAdapter` anymore. You need to derive a new class from `CursorAdapter` and use that.

Conditionally loading the images is not as trivial as it seems. I recommend using the Android Query library [image loading methods](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/#Image_Loading) which support placeholders, fallbacks, and asynchronous loading - just what you need.